# how to use replaceall function in an sqlite where clause

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need to do the following query in sqlite:

```
select * from table  where field = "somekindofdata"
```

however, I need to first remove all the special characters from field before I do the comparison. In java, it would look something like this:

```
 field = field.replaceAll("[\\s+\\W+]","");
```

> is this possible ?

Comment: there is no regex support in sqlite ... so obviosuly only REPLACE with all special chars would help

Comment: how would you do that ?

Comment: *how would you do that ?* seriously? `REPLACE( .... REPLACE(REPLACE(field, 'special_char_1', ''), 'special_char_2', '')..., 'special_char_n', '')`